# c#: How do I determine if the ScrollBar for a Scrollable control is currently displayed?

Tags: c#, controls, resize, scrollbar, scroll

Is there a way for me to check if the Scrollbar for a control is currently displayed or not?  I want to use it so I can determine how to size the children of the Scrollable control, which is somewhat dependent on whether or not the ScrollBar is displayed (the Scrollable control can be dynamically resized).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For controls with the AutoScroll property try the HorizontalScroll and VerticalScroll Visible properties:

```
// Checks horizontal scrollbar visibity.
yourScrollableControl.HorizontalScroll.Visible;

// Checks horizontal scrollbar visibity.
yourScrollableControl.VerticalScroll.Visible;
```