# AutoScroll mode doesn't hide scrollbar properly

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, scrollbar

I have one `Panel` and when I click on add `Button` I add one `Control` under other added controls. When I click on another `Button` I remove `Control` which was added as last.
This works fine. On that panel I have `AutoScroll` setting set to `True` and when I add more controls it properly appears and I can use it. When I remove some controls `Panel` properly hides `ScrollBar` **ONLY** if the "animation" on that `ScrollBar` doesn't run at that time.

1. If no animation is running on that `ScrollBar` it disapears properly - doesn't matter if you have mouse over it or not.
2. If you have mouse over the `ScrollBar` and quickly move over the remove `Button` and click before `ScrollBar`s animation is finished the `Control` is removed, but the inactive `ScrollBar` is still there. In `Button`s click handler I tried to call `Invalidate`, `Update` and `Refresh` methods over the `Panel` but nothing works.

I tested this only on `Windows 7`.

If you don't know what I mean please try to look at this short video (20s without sound): http://youtu.be/-0EfRXrGbuc

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So here is one (add panel and two buttons):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Add(new Button() { Top = panel1.Controls.Count * 30 });
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Controls.Count > 0)
            panel1.Controls.RemoveAt(panel1.Controls.Count - 1);
        panel1.Refresh();
    }
```

I am able to reproduce the problem

> *it's winforms, baby* (c).

Possible workaround is to call `Refresh()` by using e.g. `Timer` or some of mouse events (it will not prevent issue, but use will easily fix it by e.g. moving mouse inside `panel1`) or you can postpone the possibility of deleting buttons itself for a short time after `panel1.MouseLeave`. All this kind of workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I hoped that there is some better way, but now I don't see any, so based on [answer from Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29968728/1108200) I decided to use `Timer` and cobined it with checking pixel `Color` to determine if the `ScrollBar` is still visible.

```
private Timer _timer = new Timer {Interval = 500};

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _timer.Tick += TimerOnTick;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        var wasVisible = panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible;
        panel1.Controls.RemoveAt(panel1.Controls.Count - 1);
        buttons.RemoveAt(buttons.Count - 1);

        if (wasVisible != panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible)
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }
}

private bool IsBackgroundColor()
{
    var point = panel1.Location;
    point.Offset(panel1.Width - 9, panel1.Height - 11);
    point = PointToScreen(point);

    Image imgScreen = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(imgScreen))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(point, new Point(0, 0), new Size(1, 1));
        gr.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        gr.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));

        var color = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
        return color.R == panel1.BackColor.R && color.G == panel1.BackColor.G && color.B == panel1.BackColor.B;
    }
}

private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (!IsBackgroundColor() && !panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible)
    {
        panel1.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

I was not able to use `Panel.DrawToBitmap` because it doesn't draw `ScrollBars`. I also start the `Timer` only when the `ScrollBar` was visible and now it shouldn't be.
It is important to mention that the pixel `Color` checking is possible only if you know the `Color` which should be there if the `ScrollBar` is hidden. It is not necessary have to be `Panel.BackColor`.

Comment: `IsBackgroundColor` seems overkill to me. Perhaps you can determine if scrollbar is visible [somehow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1591710/1997232) differently?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, because `Panel.VerticalScroll.Visible` is set properly and I use that behaviour to check if the `ScrollBar` should or should not be visible.